# How do I get access to the RSS B Overleaf template?

Tags: publications, mathematics, statistics, latex

I'm looking to publish in RSS B, but am having some issues finding the template. This is my first publication, so very new to this. The [website](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/pages/general-instructions) directs me to the [following template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/oup-general-template/ybpypwncdxyb), but this clearly looks different to articles published in RSS B, such as [this one](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/85/2/179/7058918). I'm not sure if this belongs on the Latex forum instead, but thought it perhaps is more of a general academia question because I don't need specific Latex help.

Comment: Many if not most journals do not use LaTeX to generate their final PDF. hence, the LaTeX template output will not look like the final journal layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links you share look like the direct to the publisher's template and you're using the correct package.

In my own experience, most journals (outside of some math journal) do not use LaTeX for typesetting their final product. Instead, their system turns the LaTeX document into another format which becomes a PDF (for paper) and htlm for the web.